# C# Asynchronous Method Callback

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin

I'm building a test app for fun and all is going great so far, but I've bumped into an issue. I have a label in my Storyboard and I can set the text in the `viewDidLoad()` method. However, I'm also making an HTTP request to retrieve and parse some JSON data using asynchronous methods. In order to follow the single responsibility principle, this is done in a separate class. So in the init method of my view controller, I'm calling the `StoreData ()` method on this class. It looks something like this:

```
public HomeViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    pc = new PersonCollection ();
    pc.StoreData ();
}
```

My question is: how can I set the text on the label AFTER the asynchronous `StoreData ()` method has completed? Can I set a callback of some kind?

Regards

Comment: If you want something async first of all you shouldn't do it in the constructor since you can't handle an await

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
public HomeViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
  Setup();
}
async void Setup()
{
   var pc = new PersonCollection ();
   await pc.StoreData ();
   // Set The text of the label here

}
```

Comment: never ever use async void ... thats fire and forget!! Look at the Do's and Don'ts from here: http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/31

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it.

```
public HomeViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
  LoadValues();
}
async Task LoadValues()
{
  var pc = new PersonCollection ();
  var jsonObject=await pc.StoreData ();
  InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
   textFieldInstance.Text= jsonObject.Name;
  });
 }
```